# How to send iMessage using appleScript on Mac with effects(like slam effect)

Tags: swift, macos, applescript, imessage

right now I am able to send message using appleScript is there a way of adding effects(like fireworks, slam, invisible ink) to it. I know mac cannot saw the effects but iphone can